# while loop keep timing out, can't figure out why(Hackerrank problem)

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I'm doing the repeatedString problem on Hackerrank and my code won't past all the cases. My code seem right, but it would timeout when taking a large integer

I tried using different for loops but i can't seem to figure it out, I'm somewhat new to coding. I tried doing an if statement saying if s equal 'a' then count equal n, but that don't help it pass all test cases. I'm pretty sure you can google the repeatedStr problem if you need to see it.

From the code i put i expect count to equal n.

```
function repeatedString(s, n) {
    let count = 0
    let subStr = ''

    while (subStr.length <= n) { //it times out
        for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
            let element = s[i]
            if (element) {
                subStr += element
            }
        }
    }
    for (let j = 0; j < subStr.length - 1; j++){
        let element = subStr[j]
        if (element === 'a') {
            count++
        }
    }
    return count
}

repeatedString('a', 100000000)
```

Comment: On line 8 you have `if(element)`? If element what? Is that not supposed to be something else in those brackets?

Comment: Also, you're only passing the letter 'a' into your function?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the challenge: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/repeated-string/problem

The main problem is the `while` loop and the `for` loop.

The `while` loop is checking for `string.length <= n` and the `for` loop is checking for `i < n` and increasing n.

The for loop will break when the `i  = n`, so when the `subStr.length == n`. However, the while condition won't break because **substr.length is still equal to n**

I'd suggest to keep everything in one single loop as either the while or the for are redundant (you just need one loop).

```
// replace the while and for loop with this
let i = 0
while (subStr.length <= n) {
    let element = s[i]
    if (element) {
        subStr += element
    }
    i++;
}
```

Finally, another comment on how to optimize this problem: Instead of building the whole list of strings and counting, you can think this problem as a division solution or on how many times you can enter the string in a given length. You know you have the letter a `X` times in your string. 
If you know that you can enter the length of this string `Y` times in the length they gave you, you just have to do X*Y to get the number of `a`s in the string. Of course, you will have to play with the remainder of the division, as the number of items that enter in the length won't be an enter number, but a fraction

---

Also I can't add comments, but

1. the question is tagged as javascript and
2. `if (element)` is an assertion to validate if `element` is not undefined, which is the case when you are accessing in an out of bounds array in JS

Comment: It don't seem to be passing its giving me the wrong output. Also, I fixed up the code a little. Under the second for loop it was suppose to be i < s.length instead of i<n

Comment: I think the code is causing it to timeout..thats why I used the for loop..I'm trying to keep reading the string from index zero to the last index and then repeat if necessary but i don't know how to do that.I thought the for loop could help with that compared to using the while loop alone